# How to read and write using block ram?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, hdl, spartan

How to read and write using block ram in spartan 3?

I read in sim.pdf a manual of xilinix that each write needs one clock cycle and each read too as the BRAMs are synchronus. Are we supposed to make a finite state machine free each of the write and read operations of the ram ?

Comment: You'll probably have to explain your problem better before anyone can realistically provide you with anything helpful.

Comment: Have you read the [App Note](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp463.pdf)? It's been a while since I did this, but I don't recall spending a lot of time or effort on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as `dual-port RAM`, so you can read an write in one cycle from different addresses. Have a look at [xapp463](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp463.pdf).